# C# get string out of DataTable and send it via tcp

Tags: c#, string, tcp, datatable

im trying to get an string out of a PostgreSQL database and send it via TCP to another client.

```
string dataTable = Database.DtConvertToString(Database.SelectData("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE user_id = 3"));
```

should give me the **actual** username but it just gives me the name of the column "username"

The method :

```
public static string DtConvertToString(DataTable dt)
        {
            string rw = "";
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dr.Table.Columns)
                {
                    rw = dc.ToString();
                    if (rw.Contains(",")) rw = "\"" + rw + "\"";
                    builder.Append(rw + ",");
                }
                builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way too complicated:

```
string dataTable = Database.SelectData("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE user_id = 3").Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
```

If you *really* want to preserve the `DtConvertToString()` method, it should look more like this:

```
public static string DtConvertToString(DataTable dt, bool showHeaders = true)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (showHeaders)
    {
        var delimiter = "";
        foreach(var c in dt.Columns)
        {
           var colName = c.ColumnName;
           if (colName.Contains(","))  colName = $"\"{colName}\"";
           result.Append(delimiter).Append(colName);
           delimiter = ",";
        }
        result.AppendLine();
    }

    for (int r = 0;i<dt.Rows.Count;r++)
    {
        var row = dt.Rows[r].ItemArray;
        var delimiter = "";
        foreach(var col in row)
        {
            if (col.Contains(",")) col = $"\"{col}\"";
            result.Append(delimiter).Append(col);
            delimiter = ",";
        }
        result.AppendLine();
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Additionally, I'm very concerned about the `SelectData()` method. Code like this tends to force you to write code with HUGE GAPING SQL INJECTION VULNERABILITIES... the kind of thing where a year from now you finally find out your app was hacked six months ago, all your user data was leaked to the dark web, and your internal systems are now being held for a bitcoin ransom.

Comment: Oh wow thank you that demotivated me alot :D
Im just learning and probably never gonna release that application but how to do it correct or more safe?

Comment: @Mendax Sorry, but there are two things that are too important to do wrong, even in proof of concept and learning projects. They are password handling (not seen here) and SQL injection (definitely can happen here). Take a few minutes to learn about parameterized queries, and then adjust the program according to _ALWAYS_ use the technique, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll get on it.